# Select with a where clause and without it in the same query

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm trying to find a way to sum amounts that match a specific term, and also amounts that don't match it. For example, if my table looks like this

```
user  amount  description
1     34      bike
1     78      toys
2     3       fuel
2     12      bike
```

I'm trying to get a table that will look like this in the end:

```
user   amount spent on bike  amount spent total
1      34                    112
2      12                    15
```

I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement within a [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) grouping:

```
SELECT user,
       SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'bike' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) bike_amount,
       SUM(amount) total_amount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user
```